# How to release stories and features from board in Kanban VSTS 2018?

Tags: azure-devops

We are migrating to VSTS from JIRA. And based on experience working with Kanban in JIRA I am confused on how to release items from the Kanban board in VSTS. Basically, when the item is finished we move it to Closed. But no matter what we do it still remains on the board(we were trying to add these items to iterations etc.).

The core issue that we are facing is that there is no end-to-end scenario of using Kanban with VSTS described in the Web. Could someone please explain us based on their experience how to properly do Kanban in VSTS or at least how to release stories(and other items) from the board?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how JIRA works as I've never used, but hopefully this explanation helps explain the board.

First, the board is visible from different levels. You can look at the board for the backlog of epic, feature and product backlog item (for Scrum) and epic, feature and user story (for Agile).
[image: Backlog Board]

There are also boards in the sprints or iterations. The board in the sprint or iterations is used to walk tasks for you backlog items through their stats.
[image: Sprint Board]

The board (at present) can only be customized from the backlog view. Here you can add additional columns which can be mapped to various states of the work item and even add additional swimlanes to organize your work as you see fit.

I'm assuming the "end-to-end" scenario you are referring to is how to make an item not appear on the board when it's done. First, this isn't possible from the iteration unless you move the item(s) to another iteration. You don't want this to happen at the iteration level simply because you want to know what took place in that sprint.

I believe what you are looking for is more of an archive option for the backlog view.

One way to achieve this is to simply filter the backlog view to sprint or iterations you are currently concerned with.
[image: Filter backlog view]

You can also simply collapse the "Done" column.
[image: Collapse Done Column]

If this still does not meat your needs, I'd suggest looking at the VSTS Marketplace for a plugin that better meets your needs. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vsts

If you still can't find anything that meet your needs, you can create your hub to display the work items in a manner that makes sense to you and your organization.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-hub